# Bootstrap Menu - My menu didn't show with the button. button is on the left while the menu goes on the right side

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle1 " data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="rep_options">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" style="    font-size: 27px;"></i>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-top: 8%; margin-left: 91%;">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </div>          
</div>
```

My menu didn't show with the button. button is on the left while the menu goes on the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<header id="header" class="active">
     header
</header>

<button id="button">Toggle</button>

<style>
header{
  display:none;
  border:solid 1px #F00;
  height: 50px;
}

header.active{
  display:block;
}

</style>

<script>

    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var header = document.getElementById("header"); 

    button.onclick = function (){
        header.classList.toggle("active");
    };
</script>
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/qab611w8/)

Answer (score 0):

You may not have included the js file for bootstrap. Include this link in your file and then try again. 
`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`